# Code generation on file change in IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, plugins, code-generation

I'm facing the following situation: I have a JSON-like structured file in my `resources` folder. Whenever I change the file, I want to automatically invoke a process, preferably a Maven plugin goal that I created, which will turn the file into a Java class. I tried achieving this in IntelliJ with different lifecycle options in Maven but had no luck.

Is Maven the right path to go down or are there other options? What I want to end up with is some kind of plugin (preferably IDE independent), that can generate Java classes from those JSON-like structures after each file save (or change).

The plugin setting I tried, including different lifecycle options such has `validate`, `generate-sources`, etc.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>com.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>schema2java-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>process-resources</phase>
            <configuration>
              <pathToSchemas>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</pathToSchemas>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>generateClasses</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

Comment: I have a similar setup in an enterprise i used to work. The process is nasty during the development phase as i had to always do a ```maven-goal``` and then obtain the classes in ```target``` so Intellij could pick it up. I stuck to using https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8533-json2pojo/ this to make my life easier. Is this something you are asking for?

Comment: You can set up [Macro](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-macros-in-the-editor.html) that would invoke a Maven goal and assign a shortcut to it (e.g. same as file save). There is also [Save Actions plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7642-save-actions/).

Comment: @SiddarthSreeni Yes, however I am looking for an automated process to achieve this, so I dont have to move the files on every change.

Comment: @Andrey Looking through this, it seems to be viable - but as you mentioned, a bit clunky. Does anyone know how `Lombok` is achieving their code generation? Is there a way to piggy-back on `annotation processing` for non-Java files?